# How to remove backspace character from the end of the string?

Tags: php

Litteraly, I am killing myself over this. It should be a small thing, but I spent around several hours already on this.

```
function ssl_encrypt($pass, $data) {

    $salt = substr(md5(mt_rand(), true), 8);

    $key = md5($pass . $salt, true);
    $iv = md5($key . $pass . $salt, true);

    $ct = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data,
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return base64_encode('Salted__' . $salt . $ct);
}

 $key = ssl_encrypt('super', trim($_POST['pass']));
```

I am ecrypting a string and saving to file with:

```
 $value = $_POST['service'] . "=" . $key . "\n";


 file_put_contents($file, $value , FILE_APPEND);
```

And it outputs something like this:

U2FsdGVkX1+0NB4++Kx28hUWNGwIqBoabI2O22U1TbpJ0n4FhzZvGtmSWiP7VOZj⏎

My thought that this last symbol is this "\n" from

```
 $value = $_POST['service'] . "=" . $key . "\n";
```

I even tried something like this:

```
   $value = $_POST['service'] . "=" . $key.PHP_EOL;

        $fh = fopen($file,"a+");

        fwrite($fh, $value); //write to txtfile

        fclose($fh);
```

Still it outputs this:

U2FsdGVkX1+0NB4++Kx28hUWNGwIqBoabI2O22U1TbpJ0n4FhzZvGtmSWiP7VOZj⏎

How to get rid of that last backspace symbol? Please note that substring is not an option in this case.

this is how I decrypt:

```
function ssl_decrypt($pass, $data) {
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
    $ct = substr($data, 16);

    $key = md5($pass . $salt, true);
    $iv = md5($key . $pass . $salt, true);

    $pt = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ct,
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return $pt;
}

$Loader = new josegonzalez\Dotenv\Loader($pathtoenv);
```

// Parse the .env file

```
$environment = (new josegonzalez\Dotenv\Loader($pathtoenv))
              ->parse()
              ->toArray();


$digitalpass = ssl_decrypt('super', (string)$_ENV['digital']);
```

Comment: `PHP_EOL` would also be `\n` (or `\r\n` on windows). If you're on linux, you could check what the character actually is using `hexdump -C` (or use PHP's `chr()`). Btw, you'd need the `\n` since you append - otherwise you can't separate the records when you read the file. A simple `trim()` around that string should remove that last newline character, though.

Comment: can't you use `substr($output, 0, -1);`?

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be many methods to do it:

- Use substr() to remove the last character: `substr($output, 0, -1);`
- Use chop() to remove the string that you want: `chop($output,"⏎");`
- Or maybe use trim(), like Kenney said: `trim($output)`

Answer (score 1):

Use following snippet to remove all non-printable characters from string:

```
$trimmedVal = preg_replace("/\s+|[[:^print:]]/", "", $value)
```